# Selenium Action class is not doing mouse hover for the second time on same webelement

Tags: javascript, java, c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
Actions action = new Actions(Driver);
action.MoveToElement(webelement).ClickAndHold().Perform();
```

I have used the above code to mouse hover the Web Element. It is working fine.
When I try to do mousehover for the same Web Element second time using the above code it is not working.

Is their any reason why mousehover is not working second time?

Comment: You are not releasing the mouse button and after holding it. May be that is the reason.

Comment: What I need to do for that. I have written the above code as separate method and I am calling the method where it fails on second time.

Comment: please check my answer.

Comment: It is not working. When I use the command Release, even first time it is not working.

Comment: to move over on a element,  no need to click and hold the element. you can with out it. you can just try action.MoveToElement(webelement)).Perform();

Answer (score 0):

You may need to release the mouse holding as given below.

```
Actions action = new Actions(Driver); 
action.MoveToElement(webelement).ClickAndHold().Release().Perform();
```

And No need to click and hold if you only want to mouse over. You  can mouse over on a element with following code.

```
Actions action = new Actions(Driver); 
action.MoveToElement(webelement).perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

`ClickAndHold()` method that you're using, is not releasing the the mouse. 

Try to use below code:

```
WebElement elem = driver.FindElement(--USE YOUR BY ELEMENT HERE--);

Actions builder = new Actions(driver);  
builder.MoveToElement(elem).Perform();//this will hover to YOUR ELEMENT
Thread.Sleep(1000);                   //avoid using this type of wait. Try to use wait until.

driver.FindElement(--USE HERE YOUR SEPECIFIC ELEMENT--).Click();  //this will click on SEPECIFIC ELEMENT
```

Comment: @Kriez Can you please implement this answer and let me know your feedback

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method ,I am using it and it worked for me every time :

```
public static void moveTo(WebElement element){
    Actions action=new Actions(BrowserUtilities.driver);
    action.moveToElement(element).build().perform();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to `Mouse Hover` by using `ClickAndHold()` from the `Actions` Class for the second time as follows :

```
Actions action = new Actions(Driver);
action.MoveToElement(webelement).ClickAndHold().Perform();
```

**`clickAndHold()`** method basically **`Clicks (without releasing) at the current mouse location.`**. So it may not help us. But to simply **`Mouse Hover`** you don't need to `Click and Hold`. We can simply **`MoveToElement`** and invoke **`Perform()`** to achieve the same as follows :

```
new Actions(Driver).MoveToElement(webelement).Perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is in python you can use same feature in your language
#First time use normally

```
actions = ActionChains(self.driver)
actions.move_to_element(admin_tab).perform()
```

#second time use reset action before using mouse hover

```
actions.reset_actions()# to reset mouse hover
actions = ActionChains(self.driver)
actions.move_to_element(admin_tab_new).perform()
```